# Labelfield text not wrapping

Tags: blackberry

The below class extends labelfield but when I display a large amount text it does'nt wrap to a new line. The text just trails across the screen. When I use LabelField the text wraps. Do I need to update the paint method?

Thanks

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.DrawStyle;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;

public class FCLabelField extends LabelField {

    private Object text;
    private Font font;
    private int colour;
    private long style;

    public FCLabelField(Object text, long style , Font font, int colour) {
        super(text, style);
        this.text = text;
        this.font = font;
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {

        graphics.setColor(colour);
        graphics.setFont(font);
        graphics.drawText(text.toString(), 0, 0, DrawStyle.HCENTER, getContentWidth());


    }
}
```

This works -

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.DrawStyle;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;

public class FCLabelField extends LabelField {

    private Object text;
    private Font font;
    private int colour;
    private long style;

    public FCLabelField(Object text, long style , Font font, int colour) {
        super(text, style);
        this.text = text;
        this.colour = colour;
        super.setFont(font);
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {

        graphics.setColor(this.colour);
        super.paint(graphics);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I wonder, instead of doing the `graphics.drawText` yourself, could you just run the setColor and setFont statements, then call `super.paint(graphics)`?  That ought to fix your problem.

Comment: @Scott W You might as well promote your comment into an answer.

Comment: Tried that and the line wraps but the font is not updated. So it fixed oen bug but seems to cause another.

Comment: Setting the font on the super class works. See edits to question. Im not sure why ? Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first version you are overriding the `paint` method and not calling the superclass' `paint` method. In the second, you are, this allows the code in the base class to paint the text.

If you don't want to call the superclass' `paint` method, you have to change your paint method to calculate the extent of the string you're going to draw and to split it at the appropriate points, making multiple calls to `drawText` to draw each fragment separately at a different y location. That's what the `paint` method in `LabelField` does by default, so you need to emulate it.

When you do call the superclass `paint` method, the reason setting the font on the superclass works and setting the font in your `paint` method doesn't is because the superclass' `paint` method is calling `setFont` on the `Graphics` object, overwriting what you just did in your `paint` method.